# Overloaded method constructor FlinkKafkaConsumer010 with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

I have this scala file with this imports and this code. I don't know how to solve this overload constructor problem :

```
package uimp
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.
{SimpleStringSchema,JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema}
import org.apache.flink.core._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{FlinkKafkaConsumer010}
import java.util.Properties
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode

object Silocompro {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  // set up the execution environment
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

 //...more code

 val myConsumerDemographic = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[ObjectNode]("topic_demographic", new org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), propertiesTopicDemographic)

 // ...more code
```

And I have this build.sbt to solve all above dependencies:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

val flinkVersion = "1.9.0"

val flinkDependencies = Seq(
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion  ,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion ,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-base" % flinkVersion ,
"org.apache.flink" % "flink-core" % flinkVersion ,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion, 
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.10" % flinkVersion ,
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.10.1")
```

But I have this error after assembly:

Overloaded method constructor FlinkKafkaConsumer010 with alternatives

Any help to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably omit the type argument. See this [example|https://github.com/zqhxuyuan/kafka-book/blob/master/flink/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/Kafka010Example.scala] for a working solution. Btw any reason to use the 0.10 connector instead of a more recent one?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you.

check your FlinkKafkaConsumer010() Method,you import a mistake dependence which from package
"org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization" ,the ture dependence of is in flink-core.jar.

The problem may lie in not referencing Flink's dependency or chose the wrong import class.